# How to find the maximum value subject to constraints

Tags: algebra-precalculus, linear-programming

I am currently enrolled in a college algebra course and am having difficulty finding the solution to the following problem since it is not covered in our textbook or in class. Any helpful hints or advice on how to start would be appreciated. Thanks!

Find the maximum value of $$z = 2x + 5y$$ subject to the constraints

$x \geq 5$

$y \geq 4$

$4x+3y \leq 56$

$x+y \leq 16$

Comment: This is a linear programming problem !

Graphing these constraints will make this easier to solve !

Comment: This is definitely in either your textbook or class.

Comment: Try converting the inequality constraints into equality constraints by using slack and surplus variables.

Comment: You can transform the variables $x,y$ into $u,v$: $u=x-5$ and $v=y-4$. Thus $u,v \geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

Graphing the constraints in blue and the iso-$z$ lines in red, we get:

[image]

the values of $z$ increasing for larger $x$ and $y$, as expected from the formula. We can find the maximum $z$ at $(5,11)$.